# text alignment in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using android studio, and for the below code, when the cursor was at the beginning of the word *Default*, and I pressed Enter key on the keyboard, the cursor moves to the next line but the word *Default* remained at its same position, and every time i press enter key the text do not move but only the cursor.

Please let me know how can if it possible to fix this issue in android studio

**code**

```
        default:
            Log.wtf(TAG, SubTag.msg("onReceive", "UNHANDELED CASE in prevBondState.ACTION_CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED."));
            break;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had something similar happen to me in the latest version of Android Studio when creating a `newInstance()` method in a `Fragment`. Android Studio automatically constructed some boilerplate code, but pressing the `return` key would only cycle through to pre-set lines, rather than actually creating a line break.

To resolve it, I only needed to keep pressing `return` until it exited the method, at which point I could go back and edit lines as normal. Perhaps this a case of something similar occurring with a `switch` statement.

Comment: is it a bug , i also cant make the cases of the switch statement indented

Comment: @LetsamrIt In the case of my example I think it was intended to be a convenience feature, but it can be irritating.